# Solaris 10, change partition size

Tags: partition, solaris

I have a ultra 10 with solaris 10. I would like to increase the size of the / partition (by reducing /export/home). I'm rarely working with solaris. Some "hands on" advice would be great :)

df -h gives:

```
Filsystem            storlek anv�nda tillg. kapacitet monterat p
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0      5,8G   4,8G   947M    84%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   214M   1,4M   212M     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
swap                   212M     0K   212M     0%    /tmp
swap                   212M    56K   212M     1%    /var/run
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7      119G    66M   118G     1%    /export/home
```

EDIT:
Output from `prtvtoc /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0`

```
* /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 partition map
*
* Dimensions:
*     512 bytes/sector
*     255 sectors/track
*      16 tracks/cylinder
*    4080 sectors/cylinder
*   65535 cylinders
*   65533 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
*
*                          First     Sector    Last
* Partition  Tag  Flags    Sector     Count    Sector  Mount Directory
    0      2    00    1052640  12244080  13296719   /
    1      3    01          0   1052640   1052639
    2      5    00          0 267374640 267374639
    7      8    00   13296720 254077920 267374639   /export/home
```

The machine is from 1998. For the last 7-8 years it has had a laid-back but critical job, being a license server. The hw and os is so stable that I usually forget about its existance :) I only get reminded when we have a power break every second year or so, and when a license file is to be updated. I cleared the /var/crash dir and that gave me the 947M available at / ( / was 100% full). From the output of prtvtoc I'm guessing that I have 1GB swap that I could use to extend / @schily?? But since I guess that the now available 900M will be good for another year or five. I think I will avoid messing with the system and keep it as it is :) Thank you guys for the help and guidance anyway!

Comment: what is the size of `/var/log` ? (`du -sh /var/log` or `du -sk /var/log` ) Please, edit you post with a text copy (not a picture) for the answer.

Comment: /var/log is tiny, du -sh /var/log -> 15K I cleaned /var/crash/'hostname', there were some dumps there)
 (PS. I used a picture because the formatting of the table was totally messed with text)

Comment: I still think /var partition is missing, what is /var size ?

Comment: du -sh /var -> 107M   /var

Comment: What's the output from `prtvtoc /dev/dskc0t0d0`?  It is possible to grow a UFS file system, per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3937/6mjgeafop/index.html.  Unfortunately, growing the root file system likely isn't all that easy.  A reinstall where you **do not** accept the default disk layout might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

The root partition is usually the first partition but in some cases, the swap is located before the root partition.

You cannot shrink a filesystem and in special you cannot from the beginning.

You would first need to create some free space after the root partition....

If you have luck, the swap partition is past root and if you disable swap and reboot, you could grow your root.

The disadvantage is: If you do not have another temporary disk that allows you to copy /export/home to and back, you will need to swap into a plain file in /export/home after your changes but as your /export/home is nearly empty, this would be OK. The first you need to do is to find information about the current partitioning.

Call e.g. `format` and select the disk, then type `par` followed by `pr` and then 2x `quit`.